# My sql sum function error

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have the following the script that when I run it returns the correct information relating to items and the correct pricing based on customer specific set prices.

It all works as it should but I am having trouble when I want to sum the total of all items and group it by order id. I did try a sum function just in front of the truncate but this returned the incorrect price.

Cheers

```
SELECT
w.ward_name,
orders.id as orderID,
 if ((SELECT count(price) from price_file where op.product_id =  price_file.item_id and w.pf_id = price_file.pf_id)>0,(SELECT price from price_file where op.product_id = price_file.item_id and w.pf_id = price_file.pf_id),(SELECT price from products where op.product_id = products.id) )as price,
TRUNCATE(op.product_quantity * (SELECT(price)),2) as 'total price',
from_unixtime(orders.date_filled, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'filled date' FROM   `orders` join wards w ON orders.ward_id = w.id
join order_products op on orders.id = op.order_id
and op.product_quantity > 0
AND from_unixtime(date_filled,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-04-01'
and from_unixtime(date_filled,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-04-30'
and ward_category = 138
and orders.id = 13522
```

Sample Data

This is what I see now

```
ward_name   orderID     price   total price     filled date     
Customer    13522   0.10    20.00       2017-04-06
Customer    13522   0.10    20.00       2017-04-06
Customer    13522   0.10    20.00       2017-04-06
Customer    13522   0.10    20.00       2017-04-06
```

What I want to See

```
ward_name   orderID     price   total price     filled date     
Customer    13522   0.10    80.00       2017-04-06
```

Hope this helps

I have tried this

```
SELECT
w.ward_name,
orders.id as orderID,
 if ((SELECT count(price) from price_file where op.product_id = price_file.item_id and w.pf_id = price_file.pf_id)>0,(SELECT price from price_file where op.product_id = price_file.item_id and w.pf_id = price_file.pf_id),(SELECT price from products where op.product_id = products.id) )as price,
TRUNCATE(op.product_quantity * (SELECT(price)),2) as 'total price',
from_unixtime(orders.date_filled, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'filled date' FROM `orders` join wards w ON orders.ward_id = w.id
join order_products op on orders.id = op.order_id
and op.product_quantity > 0
AND from_unixtime(date_filled,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-04-01'
and from_unixtime(date_filled,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-04-30'
and ward_category = 138
and orders.id = 13522
GROUP BY orderid
```

But it does not return the correct value. I have also tried this using the sum function and this does return a different result but it also not correct

```
SELECT
w.ward_name,
orders.id as orderID,
 if ((SELECT count(price) from price_file where op.product_id = price_file.item_id and w.pf_id = price_file.pf_id)>0,(SELECT price from price_file where op.product_id = price_file.item_id and w.pf_id = price_file.pf_id),(SELECT price from products where op.product_id = products.id) )as price,
sum(TRUNCATE(op.product_quantity * (SELECT(price)),2)) as 'total price',
from_unixtime(orders.date_filled, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'filled date' FROM  `orders` join wards w ON orders.ward_id = w.id
join order_products op on orders.id = op.order_id
and op.product_quantity > 0
AND from_unixtime(date_filled,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-04-01'
and from_unixtime(date_filled,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-04-30'
and ward_category = 138
and orders.id = 13522
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Sorry yes that would help

Comment: Have just updated the question now. Thanks

Comment: if possible create a `sqlfiddle` ill fix it

Comment: as per my understanding just `sum` the final `price`  you will get the desired result

Comment: you need to use `GROUP BY` as well, however, from your question is not clear according to which attributes you need to compute the sum aggregate.

Comment: I have updated the questions so hopefully it is clearer what I am asking

Comment: Could you please provide sample data *from each of the source tables*  and show what result you expect for that sample data.